# Fitlering events with FullCalendar and an input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am trying to filter events from my calendar using the FullCalendar script, using a text box.
I managed to make it work with a dropdown menu based on other topics on Stackoverflow, but wasn't able to find one filtering the events based on the keywords in a text box.

Here's the code I have added to make the dropdown filter works:

This, to re-render the events on change.

```
$('#filter-conferencier').on('change', function () {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
        });
```

And this, for the FullCalendar options:

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'listMonth, month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
      },
      defaultView: 'listMonth',
      locale: 'fr',
      contentHeight: 600,
      navLinks: true,
      selectable: false,
      eventRender: function(event) { 
          return ['all', event.conferencier].indexOf($('#filter-conferencier').val()) >= 0;
      },
...
```

Look at the "eventRender" part.
This is how I make it work to filter events based on what is selected in that dropdown menu. And it works.

To also filter content based on what is inside this text input :

```
<input type="text" id="numero">
```

I started by adding this code:

```
$('#numero').on('input', function () {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
        });
```

And now, that's where I'm lost.
I tried changing the code of the eventRender part like this:

```
return ['all', event.conferencier].indexOf($('#filter-conferencier').val()) >= 0 && [event.numero].($('#numero').val());
```

Which doesn't work. I thought that this would check the "event.numero" of each events, and make it match with the value of what's inside the "numero" input field. I wasn't confident it would work, and it doesn't.

Here's the full "FullCalendar" code, with sample data.

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'listMonth, month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
      },
      defaultView: 'listMonth',
      locale: 'fr',
      contentHeight: 600,
      navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
      selectable: false,
      eventRender: function(event, element, view) { 
        element.find('.fc-widget-header').append("<div style='color:#fff'>Conférencier choisi</div>");
        element.find('.fc-title').append("<br/>" + event.lieu); 
        element.find('.fc-list-item-title').append("<br/>" + event.lieu); 
        element.find('.fc-list-item-title').append("<a href='" + event.lienconferencier + "'><div class='conferencier-calendrier-container'><div style='float:left;background-image:url(" + event.photoconferencier + ");width:40px;height:40px;background-size:cover;border-radius:100px;'></div><div style='float:left;padding-left:5px;font-weight:normal;'><strong>Conférencier</strong><br>" + event.conferencier + "</div></a>"); 
          return ['all', event.conferencier].indexOf($('#filter-conferencier').val()) >= 0;

      },
      selectHelper: true,
      editable: false,
      eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
      events: [
        {
          title: 'Example',
          start: '2018-05-05',
          end: '2018-05-06',
          color: '#ff0000',
          lieu: 'Montreal',
          numero: '300445',
          conferencier: 'John Doe',
          photoconferencier: 'http://www.example.com/img/profile.jpg',
          lienconferencier: 'http://www.example.com/profile/link.html',
          url: 'http://www.google.com'
        },
{
          title: 'Example2',
          start: '2018-05-08',
          end: '2018-05-010',
          color: '#ff0000',
          lieu: 'New York',
          numero: '300446',
          conferencier: 'Steve Jobs',
          photoconferencier: 'http://www.example.com/img/profile2.jpg',
          lienconferencier: 'http://www.example.com/profile/link2.html',
          url: 'http://www.apple.com'
        },
      ],
    });
```

The dropdown menu and text field code is:

```
<select id="filter-conferencier">
<option value="all">Conférencier...</option>
<option value="john-doe">John Doe</option>
<option value="steve-jobs">Steve Jobs</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="numero" placeholder="Numéro de contrat">
```

(the "element.find" parts are to add visual stuff to the listMonth view)

Any idea what I need to change to make this work?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: it's a bit hard without seeing an example of the data you're trying to filter, the filter input you've used and what the expected result should be from the sample data and inputs.

Comment: Thanks, I have added the full code of the FullCalendar part with 1 sample event data.

Comment: and what about sample input(s) and expected result in each case, to demonstrate the issue? More than one event as sample data might be better as well, to see the effects more clearly.

Comment: Just added a 2nd sample event, and the html code for the dropdown menu and text field. Thanks!

Comment: The sample above doesn't work with the dropdown list even (the values in the dropdown options never match the event objects) - I had to change it slightly: http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/572/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You weren't far off, you just needed to:

1) use indexOf() - without this there's a syntax error

2) deal with the condition where the field is empty by adding an extra value to the array

3) check that indexOf returns a value of 0 or more

It actually ends up almost identical to your original version using the dropdown list - you're still just checking the value from an input field. The only real differences are the name of the input field, and the extra value used to indicate that no filter is being applied.

I have put some extra whitespace into the code here so you can more easily see the similarity of structure between the two tests:

```
return 
   ['all', event.conferencier].indexOf($('#filter-conferencier').val()) >= 0 
&& [''   , event.numero      ].indexOf($('#numero').val()             ) >= 0;
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/573/ for a working demo.

Comment: That's greaet! Thanks a lot. What about checking if "event.numero" contains instead of exact match? Would that be much different? I forgot to add that information I think. So that if you enter part of "event.numero" of a specific event, it would still be shown instead of having to be the exact match. Example : If code is 5605, and you enter 56, it should appear. Thanks!

Comment: If you wanted to match only part of the string, you'd probably want to make use of something like  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes against the numero field itself, rather than this array-based syntax. Essentially you're looking for part of a string within another string. And yes you forgot to include that in the question. You can always ask again about it after this question if you can't figure it out. It doesn't seem to be a fullCalendar question, it's entirely focused on the string matching. Where the data's from is irrelevant.

Comment: Alright thanks a lot! Helped me a lot. I will try to make it work with "includes". Thanks again!